# How do I execute a command in an iTerm window from the command line?

Tags: iterm

How do I run an iTerm session from the command line, passing in the command which is to be executed in the iTerm window?

The xterm analog is `-e`, i.e.

```
xterm -e sleep 10
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with Alex, using the AppleScript the best way to go.

Here is my "iterm" script that I chmod as executable and have it in a directory that is in my path. I can use it like this:

Quote enclosed shell arguments:

```
iterm "ls -l"
```

Pass multiple cmds to run:

```
iterm "calculatesomthing" "exit"
```

Pass multiple cmds, semicolon separtated:

```
iterm "cd ~/mediaprojects; ./gitSyncAll; exit"
```

The self enclosed bash/Applescript:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -d '' script <<'EOF'
on run argv
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set myterm to (make new terminal)
    tell myterm
        launch session "Default"
        tell the last session
            repeat with arg in argv
               say arg
               write text arg
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end run
EOF
echo "$script" | osascript ``-'' $@
```

FYI: You might want to remove the "say" command, I use it as a remote/audible notification of each cmd being executed. I pass a bunch of cmds to multiple custom iTerm profiles/shell that gets tiled to a large flat screen to show the status of an complex multi-DC Azure deployment...

PS: I added a gist as the quotes in the last line of the script were not cut/pasting properly for someone @ https://gist.github.com/sushihangover/7563e1707e98cdf2b285

Comment: I get the error: 78:86: execution error: The variable terminal is not defined. (-2753). I'm using iterm2. Any advice?

Answer (score 17):

I had found the [official documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html), but hadn't thought to wrap the Applescript up with osascript like SushiHangover- very nice.  His answer didn't work for me, probably because I'm using the latest beta 3.0 version, so here's one that does work (and also simplifies a bit).

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript - "$@" <<EOF
on run argv
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set new_term to (create window with default profile)
    tell new_term
        tell the current session
            repeat with arg in argv
               write text arg
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end run
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on your answer I wrote a script to write text to current session.  https://gist.github.com/LeoUfimtsev/82e7e827b6bfb1000f422a98f2008cc3

Answer (score 5):

You're best off using Applescript for this. iTerm2 has some [examples](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/Applescript) of scripts. The documentation is a little shoddy, but those examples should give you an idea of where to start.

You can wrap the Applescript string in a bash script and then launch it using `osascript`:

```
#~/bin/bash
tell application "iTerm"
    # etc...
    exec command "$@"
```

Then running the script is as simple as:

```
./run-in-iterm.sh "echo 'hello world'"
```

Comment: I agree, AppleScript is the way to go, I added an Answer that has the self-enclosed bash/AppleScript script that I use.

Comment: Thank you, here is the examples for last verstion of iTerm2: https://iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html